# how do i select values from different table between selected date

Tags: php, mysql

this is what i did. I have tried a sql query for getting  values between 2 dates  from 2 multiple tables  that have same area. But i got a result that have similar dates for both `$from_date` and `$to_date`. But I need all values that satisfy my condition i.e. `BETWEEN '$from_date' AND '$to_date'`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.amount_in_sqft, b.price_in_sqft, a.category
FROM sale_apartment AS a
INNER JOIN reqr_apartments AS b
    on a.area = b.area AND a.category = b.category
WHERE a.area='$area'
  AND b.category BETWEEN '$from_date' AND '$to_date'
GROUP BY a.category
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems strange to use a GROUP BY clause without any aggregation functions. Maybe try to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

try with this:

```
SELECT distinct a.amount_in_sqft, b.price_in_sqft, a.category 
FROM sale_apartment AS a 
INNER JOIN reqr_apartments AS b
    ON a.area = b.area and a.category = b.category
WHERE a.area = '$area' 
  AND b.category BETWEEN '$from_date' AND '$to_date' 
GROUP BY a.amount_in_sqft, b.price_in_sqft, a.category
```

Comment: i used this method. but Still getting Same output

Comment: witout ** just : GROUP BY a.amount_in_sq ft,b.price_in_sq ft, a.category

Comment: i need all values from different table with two dates and same area

Comment: (INNER JOIN re qr_apartments as b on a.area = b.area)  why you add re ?

Comment: try whit this SELECT a.amount_in_sqft, b.price_in_sqft, a.category
FROM sale_apartment a, reqr_apartments b
WHERE a.area = b.area 
AND a.category = b.category
AND a.area='$area'
AND (b.category BETWEEN '$from_date' AND '$to_date')
GROUP BY a.amount_in_sqft, b.price_in_sqft, a.category